# How to create svg shape from string markup (template)

Tags: javascript, svg, dagre-d3

i'm very new to SVG so this maybe a stupid question, but i would like to **create an SVG shape based on some markup** for example, lets say i want to create a lot of cards that have this markup:

```
var svg_test_label = [
    '<g class="rotatable">',
      '<g class="scalable">',
        '<rect class="card"/><image/>',
       '</g>',
       '<text class="rank"/><text class="name"/>',
    '<g class="btn add"><circle class="add"/><text class="add">+</text></g>',
    '<g class="btn del"><circle class="del"/><text class="del">-</text></g>',
    '<g class="btn edit"><rect class="edit"/><text class="edit">EDIT</text></g>',
    '</g>'].join('');
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: @RobertLongson can you please show me an example ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: @RobertLongson i mean an example of how to inject it as an svg object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On behalf of Robert:

```js
var svg_test_label = [
    '<g class="rotatable">',
      '<g class="scalable">',
        '<rect class="card"/><image/>',
       '</g>',
       '<text class="rank"/><text class="name"/>',
    '<g class="btn add"><circle class="add"/><text class="add">+</text></g>',
    '<g class="btn del"><circle class="del"/><text class="del">-</text></g>',
    '<g class="btn edit"><rect class="edit"/><text class="edit">EDIT</text></g>',
    '</g>'].join('');


document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "<svg>" + svg_test_label + "</svg>";
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```